# Cannot read single quote and double quote character and some of the characters around it in PDFBOX

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using Apache PDFbox to process my PDF.I need to extract text along with the  font information of each characters in the PDF for processing it further.I used processTextPosition( TextPosition text ) method to get the text and their font information.But **i cannot read the character like single quotes,double quotes and also some of the characters around it**.I examined the stream contents of the PDF.It has some numerical representation for these single and double quotes and characters around it where as it has the actual character in normal cases...Can any one please help me in solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly there is a more standard approach for extracting font from pdf, as described in the answer to this post: [How to extract font styles of text contents using pdfbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939583/how-to-extract-font-styles-of-text-contents-using-pdfbox)

And basic text extraction is described in the pdfbox wiki: http://pdfbox.apache.org/cookbook/textextraction.html