# Get font of each line using PDFBox

Tags: pdf, fonts, pdfbox

Is there a way to get the font of each line of a PDF file using PDFBox? I have tried this but it just lists all the fonts used in that page. It does not show what line or text is showed in that font.

```
List<PDPage> pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
for(PDPage page:pages)
{
Map<String,PDFont> pageFonts=page.getResources().getFonts();
for(String key : pageFonts.keySet())
   {
    System.out.println(key+" - "+pageFonts.get(key));
    System.out.println(pageFonts.get(key).getBaseFont());
    }
}
```

Any input is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Whenever you try to extract text (plain or with styling information) from a PDF using PDFBox, you generally should start trying using the `PDFTextStripper` class or one of its relatives. This class already does all the heavy lifting involved in PDF content parsing for you.

You use the plain `PDFTextStripper` class like this:

```
PDDocument document = ...;
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
// set stripper start and end page or bookmark attributes unless you want all the text
String text = stripper.getText(document);
```

This returns merely the plain text, e.g. from some R40 form:

> ```
> Claim for repayment of tax deducted 
> from savings and investments
> How to fill in this form
> Please fill in this form with details of your income for the
> above tax year. The enclosed Notes will help you (but there is
> not a note for every box on the form). If you need more help
> with anything on this form, please phone us on the number
> shown above.
> If you are not a UK resident, do not use this form – please 
> contact us.
> Please do not send us any personal records, or tax
> certificates or vouchers with your form. We will contact 
> you if we need these.
> Please allow four weeks before contacting us about your
> repayment. We will pay you as quickly as possible.
> Use black ink and capital letters
> Cross out any mistakes and write the
> correct information below
> ...
> ```

You can, on the other hand, overwrite its method `writeString(String, List<TextPosition>)` and process more information than the mere text. To add information on the name of the used font wherever the font changes, you can use this:

```
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper() {
    String prevBaseFont = "";

    protected void writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (TextPosition position : textPositions)
        {
            String baseFont = position.getFont().getBaseFont();
            if (baseFont != null && !baseFont.equals(prevBaseFont))
            {
                builder.append('[').append(baseFont).append(']');
                prevBaseFont = baseFont;
            }
            builder.append(position.getCharacter());
        }

        writeString(builder.toString());
    }
};
```

For the same form you get

> ```
> [DHSLTQ+IRModena-Bold]Claim for repayment of tax deducted 
> from savings and investments
> How to fill in this form
> [OIALXD+IRModena-Regular]Please fill in this form with details of your income for the
> above tax year. The enclosed Notes will help you (but there is
> not a note for every box on the form). If you need more help
> with anything on this form, please phone us on the number
> shown above.
> If you are not a UK resident, do not use this form – please 
> contact us.
> [DHSLTQ+IRModena-Bold]Please do not send us any personal records, or tax
> certificates or vouchers with your form. We will contact 
> you if we need these.
> [OIALXD+IRModena-Regular]Please allow four weeks before contacting us about your
> repayment. We will pay you as quickly as possible.
> Use black ink and capital letters
> Cross out any mistakes and write the
> correct information below
> ...
> ```

If you don't want the font information to be merged with the text, simply create separate structures in your method overwrite.

`TextPosition` offers a lot more information on the piece of text it represents. Inspect it!

Answer (score 4):

To add onto mkl's answer, if you are using pdfbox 2.0.8:

- Use `position.getFont().getName()` instead of `position.getFont().getBaseFont()`
- Use `position.getUnicode()` instead of `position.getCharacter()`

More information on [PDFont](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.8/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/font/PDFont.html) and [Text Position](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.8/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/text/TextPosition.html) can be found on their Javadocs online.