# Extracting font color along with font type from PDF using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, pdfbox

I need to extract Font color as well as Font type[E.g.-Black, Tahoma, Bold] from PDF by Java(Using PDFBox). Below is the code I have written to extract font type and embed the same in the extracted text.

```
public class PDFParse {

 public static void main(String args[]) {
        PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = null;
        PDDocument pdDoc = null;
        COSDocument cosDoc = null;
        File file = new File("Sample Bill.pdf");
        try {
            PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));
            parser.parse();
            cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
             pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper() {
                String prevBaseFont = "";

                protected void writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException
                {
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                    for (TextPosition position : textPositions)
                    {
                        String baseFont = position.getFont().getBaseFont();
                        if (baseFont != null && !baseFont.equals(prevBaseFont))
                        {
                            builder.append('[').append(baseFont).append(']');
                            prevBaseFont = baseFont;
                        }
                        builder.append(position.getCharacter());
                    }

                    writeString(builder.toString());
                }

            };
            pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
            pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
            pdfStripper.setEndPage(5);
            pdfStripper.setSortByPosition(true);
            String parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("sample.txt");
            out.println(parsedText);
            out.close();
           System.out.println(parsedText);
    }
}
```

How to extract the font color for each word and embed the same in the same extracted file? Thanks :)

Comment: Please have a look at the PrintTextColors example in the source code download.

Comment: You might want to merge your code (which effectively is from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25290318/1729265)) with the code from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21453780/1729265).